# How to add a scatter plot over a map of London using python

Tags: matplotlib-basemap, scatter

I am trying to plot this scatter over a map of London, but it is not correct, here is my code, the maps have different sizes and I want one map but I got 2.
This is my dataframe (dfrt) to get the scatter:

```
commonName  id  lat lon placeType   url additionalProperties2   category    key sourceSystemKey value   modified
0   River Street , Clerkenwell  BikePoints_1    51.529163   -0.109970   BikePoint   /Place/BikePoints_1 {'$type': 'Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Addit...   Description TerminalName    BikePoints  001023  2019-08-22T11:17:04.327Z
1   Phillimore Gardens, Kensington  BikePoints_2    51.499606   -0.197574   BikePoint   /Place/BikePoints_2 {'$type': 'Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Addit...   Description TerminalName    BikePoints  001018  2019-08-22T11:10:02.34Z
2   Christopher Street, Liverpool Street    BikePoints_3    51.521283   -0.084605   BikePoint   /Place/BikePoints_3 {'$type': 'Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Addit...   Description TerminalName    BikePoints  001012  2019-08-22T11:12:02.7Z
3   St. Chad's Street, King's Cross BikePoints_4    51.530059   -0.120973   BikePoint   /Place/BikePoints_4 {'$type': 'Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Addit...   Description TerminalName    BikePoints  001013  2019-08-22T11:08:02.047Z
4   Sedding Street, Sloane Square   BikePoints_5    51.493130   -0.156876   BikePoint   /Place/BikePoints_5 {'$type': 'Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Addit...   Description TerminalName
```

And this what I tried to get the plots:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
m = Basemap(projection='lcc', resolution='h',
lat_0=51.53, lon_0=0.08,
width=1E6, height=1.2E6)
m.shadedrelief()
m.drawcoastlines(color='gray')
m.drawcountries(color='gray')


a4_dims = (20, 10)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = a4_dims)

ax.scatter(dfrt['lat'], dfrt['lon'])

ax.set_title('Latitud y Longitud de la ubicación de BikePoints')
ax.set_xlabel('Latitud')
ax.set_ylabel('Longitud')
```

Could you please, help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create figure/axes twice and end up plotting 2 figures. Here is the relevant code based on yours:

```
# create figure and axes
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
ax1 = plt.gca()
m = Basemap(projection='lcc', resolution='h', \
    lat_0=51.53, lon_0=0.08,
    width=1E6, height=1.2E6, ax=ax1)
m.shadedrelief()
m.drawcoastlines(color='gray')
m.drawcountries(color='gray')

# a4_dims = (20, 10)
# fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = a4_dims)

# uncomment to do scatter plot
#ax1.scatter(dfrt['lat'], dfrt['lon'])

ax1.set_title('Latitud y Longitud de la ubicación de BikePoints')
ax1.set_xlabel('Latitud')
ax1.set_ylabel('Longitud')

plt.show()
```

and the (unfinish) plot:

[image]

**Edit 1**

For the data plot on the map, here is the code that use simple data to plot:

```
# sample data
lons = np.array([-5.371475, -1.569707, -0.892185])
lats = np.array([51.211262, 52.819886, 55.122479])
x,y = m(lons, lats)

# any of these code will plot dots on the map
#ax1.plot(*m(lons, lats), 'ro')  # OK
#ax1.plot(x, y, 'ro')            # OK
ax1.scatter(x, y, 25)            # OK
```

For data from pandas' dataframe, try to get `lons` and `lats` as follows:

```
lons = list(dfrt['lon'])
lats = list(dfrt['lat'])
```

then do as shown above.

Comment: Hi @ swatchai, it does not work :( I cant see the scatter after uncommenting. Could you please help me?

Comment: @Alexa Then, your data coordinates are probably in (long, lat) in degrees units. You might need to convert them to the projection coordinates first. Try `ax1.scatter(*m(dfrt['lon'], dfrt['lat'], 'or'))`.

Comment: @ swatchai Now I got this error: 
TypeError: input must be an array, list, tuple or scalar

Comment: @Alexa Problem with your data. Try to share it. Only some of them that represent the whole are needed.

Comment: @ swatchai thanks for your help. I share a sample of my data in my updated question. Is that ok?

Comment: By the way, another approach is using `ax1.plot(*m(dfrt['lon'], dfrt['lat'], 'or'))`.

Comment: @ swatchai: This time I got this error:  if sys.path[0] == ''